# Any difference in content extracted by pdfbox and itext

Tags: java, performance, itext, pdfbox

I am evaluating pdfbox-1.8.6 and iText-4.2.0(free) for performance. I have noticed that **content extraction is faster in iText**, but **searching words using regex in the content extracted by iText takes longer time** than pdfbox.

Extracted content and its size seems same in both cases.

Can anybody explain me on this?
My environment is ubuntu 12.04/java 1.7.

EDIT: adding sample codes.

**pdfbox**

```
//in constructor
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(bis);
textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

//in extarctContent method
textStripper.setStartPage(pageNo);
textStripper.setEndPage(pageNo);
return textStripper.getText(pdfDocument);
```

**iText**

```
//in constructor
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
reader = new PdfReader(fis);
pdfTextExtractor = new PdfTextExtractor(reader);

//in extarctContent method
return pdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pageNo);
```

**searching words**

```
StopWatch searchTime = ...
StopWatch pdfTime = ...

for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
    // fetch one page
    pdfTime.resume();
    String pageContent = pdfParserService.extractPageContent(i);
    pdfTime.suspend();
    if (pageContent == null) {
        pageContent = "";
    }

    pageContent = pageContent.replace("-\n", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\\", " ");

    searchTime.resume();
    Collection list = searchService.search(pageContent, wordList);
    searchTime.suspend();

}

pdfTime.stop();
searchTime.stop();


System.out.println(pdfTime.getTime());
System.out.println(searchTime.getTime());
```

Comment: *searching words using regex in the content extracted by itext takes longer time than pdxbox* - this sounds weird. Both iText and PDFBox return regular Java `String` instances as result. Thus, you most likely do something different when doing the regexp search. Even after your recent edit, there is not enough code to see how your comparison is working.

Comment: Hello mkl, i have updated the code

Comment: Assuming obvious stuff (the same words are sought, timers are reset between testing one library and testing the other, ...) I cannot recognize any reason for a difference. You might want to compare the data actually extracted by the two libraries, maybe there are differences...

Comment: thanks mkl for the reply. i will check for differences

Comment: By iText 4.2.0 you are likely to be referring to https://github.com/ymasory/iText-4.2.0 . Please keep in mind that this version is a fork from the official codebase, created 4 years ago by a 3rd-party developer, and that was never maintained in any way. You should consider using an official version of iText.